# Best way to display specific posts on home page?

Tags: wordpress

I'm going to help this company http://www.biofuelregion.se and make their website in wordpress. But I found one problem. They have a newsfeed on the right side of the home page. But all the little boxes with the headings like "Vi önskar ett fint 2014!", "Biogas Norr" and so on. Those are news too. Do you guys know the smartest solution to make this happen?

Like when I want to create a blogpost. I want something that I can click on or something. Maybe a button that says "Add to homepage". If it is clicked, it will show up on the homepage in a small format like those that are on the site. If i don't check that box, it will show up in the normal newsfeed on the right side.

Is there a plugin already for this? Maybe something near what I'm looking for? I've tried to find one without success.

Thank you!

/Christian

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are looking for is "sticky posts". No need for plugins if you can code.

Take a look here http://codex.wordpress.org/Sticky_Posts